# Pass variable from parent component to child component

Tags: angular

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm trying to pass the error title and message from LoginComponent to ErrorComponent.

LoginComponent :

```
export class LoginComponent  {
  @Input() public  ErrorTitle: string;
  @Input() public   ErrorMessage: string;
  title: 'Incorrect credentials';
  message: 'This password do not match any credentials'
```

```
<app-error *ngIf="isError == true" [ErrorTitle]="title" [ErrorMessage]="message"></app-error>
```

ErrorComponent :

```
<p class="text-sm font-medium text-red-700">{{ title }}</p>
<p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ message }}</p>
```

It shows me this error :

```
Property 'title' does not exist on type 'ErrorComponent'
```

So if I declare them without giving them a value, it doesn't show the error, but it's blank.

```
 title: string;
 message: string;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pass variable from parent to child component angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72047320/pass-variable-from-parent-to-child-component-angular)

Comment: No, I've already looked into it, and I don't see what I'm doing differently than them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few errors in your code.

> LoginComponent

1. The **`ErrorTitle` and `ErrorMessage` should be placed in `ErrorComponent`** but not `LoginComponent`. With existing code, you are expecting that your `LoginComponent` to received the mentioned parameters as:

```
<app-login [ErrorTitle]="/* title */" [ErrorMessage]="/* message */"></app-login>
```

2. Assign value to `title` and `message` variables should **use `=` operator**, `:` is for specifying the type.

```js
export class LoginComponent  {
  title = 'Incorrect credentials';
  message = 'This password do not match any credentials';
}
```

> ErrorComponent

1. Add **`ErrorTitle` and `ErrorMessage` input parameter.

```js
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() ErrorTitle: string;
  @Input() ErrorMessage: string;
}
```

The HTML template for `ErrorComponent` should be:

```
<p class="text-sm font-medium text-red-700">{{ ErrorTitle }}</p>
<p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ ErrorMessage }}</p>
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tpkr6w?file=src/app/login/login.component.ts)

Comment: It does work, thank you, I was thinking you need to declare the @input into login when in fact you needed to declare it into error, thank you very much !